# Can an empty language be associated with a non-empty alphabet?

Tags: formal-languages

As far as I am aware an empty language cannot contain an empty word (string). However, can it be associated with a non-empty alphabet, that simply remains completely unused?

Comment: Yes. An empty language is a language with $0$ strings, which means even the empty string is not included. The empty language is a language of every alphabet.

Comment: Many thanks indeed Rushabh

Comment: Apologies Rushabh, I have a follow-up question. When you say that the empty language is a language of every alphabet, does that also include the empty alphabet  Σ=∅?

Comment: Yes. The empty alphabet has two languages, and it is one of them.

Comment: Many thanks again Rushabh.